# Accessing a component without using the @ViewChild annotation

Tags: angular, viewchild

How could I access a subcomponent without using the @ViewChild or @ViewChildren annotations? For example:

```
SubComponent getComponent() {
    return Whatever.getComponentBySelector('selector');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you need to do is access for values then you can use `@output` to get values from child or use service and make child update the service with the relevant data. If it is what you want.